# Group of automorphisms of localization of polynomial ring

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

Let P_{n} be a polynomial ring P_{n}:=K[x_{1},...,x_{n}] and let us consider 
localization of P_{n} by prime ideal I and denote it via B_{n} and also consider
local Weyl algebra: A_{n}:=B_{n}[d_{1},...,d_{n}], where d_{i} is partial derivative
by x_{i}.

Questions:

Is there known group of automorphisms of B_{n} ?     (here n=2)

Is there known group of automorphisms of A_{n} ?      (n=1)

Comment: Do you only intend the questions for $n=2$ and for $n=1$, respectively?

Comment: Yes, here I ask the questions only for n=2 and for n=1 respectively!

Of course I would like to know the answer in general, but for the higher n it seems to be very difficult.   
 